# что означает %f?

Tags: python, форматирование

Всем привет. Я новичок в пайтоне. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что означает в ниженаписанном коде "...%f" % bill

```
def tax(bill): 
   bill *= 1.08 
   print ("With tax: %f" % bill)
   return bill 


def tip(bill): 
    bill  *= 1.15 
    print ("With tip: %f" % bill)
    return bill 


meal_cost = 100 
meal_with_tax = tax(meal_cost) 
meal_with_tip = tip(meal_with_tax)
```

Comment: Вместо `%f` подставляется значение переменной `bill` как вещественного числа (`float`). Это устаревший способ форматирования строк, лучше это делать так, как Вам указали в ответе. `print(f"With tax: {bill}")` будет даже быстрее работать (обратите внимание на `f` перед началом строки, здесь это значит не float, а format). Вот [тут](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) очень хорошо написано про это.

Answer (score 5):

Вместо `%f` подставляется `float`, `%i` - `int`, `%s` - `str`. [Статья про это.](https://python-scripts.com/string) но удобней делать так, чтобы можно было менять последовательность и не указывать тип:

```
first = "test"
second = 324
# выведет одно и тоже "Форматирование строк: 324, test"
# но второе явно удобней, а третье явно быстрей
print("Форматирование строк: %i, %s" % (second, first))
print("Форматирование строк: {1}, {0}".format(first, second))
print(f"Форматирование строк: {second}, {first}")
```

Тоесть Ваш код может выглядить так и ничего не поменяется.

```
def tax(bill): 
   bill *= 1.08 
   print ("With tax: {0}".format(bill))
   return bill 

def tip(bill): 
    bill  *= 1.15 
    print ("With tip: {0}".format(bill))
    return bill 

meal_cost = 100 
meal_with_tax = tax(meal_cost) 
meal_with_tip = tip(meal_with_tax)
```

Comment: @LiudmilaLiubarsky для принятия ответа нажмите галочку слева от него)